# Java - In terms of performance when handling Swing component views. Is it better to hide the component or just remove the component altogether?

Tags: java, swing, view, components

I am implementing a simple Java Desktop application that has a main panel where any of the views chosen by the user from the menu will be loaded. Currently, I am accomplishing this by removing the current components on the panel by invoking:

```
viewPanel.removeAll();
viewPanel.add(chosen view);
viewPanel.repaint();
```

I am wondering if it is better to create some sort of ViewManager that goes something like:

```
private final Component mainView;
private Component activeComponent;
public class ViewManager(Component main){
   mainView = main;
}

public void register(Component subview){
   mainView.add(subview, "span, grow"); // I am using MigLayout as my LayoutManager
}

public void show(Component subview){
   if(activeComponent != null){
      activeComponent.setVisible(false);
   }
   activeComponent = subview;
   activeComponent.setVisible(true);  
}
```

In this way I could somehow minimize objects that are being created and re-created over and over again, I figured that's a bit of an overhead.

Although, the second approach is probably good only for applications that contain a minimum amount of views and where switching of views are frequent because this approach could also take up a lot of memory as well, at that point maybe the idea of implementing an Object pool to limit the number of object reference can be managed is worth exploring.

Am I on the right track? Or am I thinking about it the wrong way? Or maybe, loading the views in that panel is not a very good idea in the first place, but how else could implement it?

Comment: First, you should have a look at `CardLayout`, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details.  The answer is not an easy one.  If you are creating a number of short lived objects over a short period of time, then it's likely that performance will be degraded and hiding the components might be simpler, but then that becomes complicated by the how you are laying out your component as well

Comment: I am currently using MigLayout as my Layout Manager, and I set it up where components which are currently not visible will not take up space, since that was my prior concern before. I would check CardLayout out although as much as possible I am trying to stick at using a single flexible layout manager like miglayout. Thanks for the quick answer.